# FileWriter not writing to text file (java)

Tags: java, eclipse

I am trying to write some variables to a text file once a user has inputted some data. I have had it working before but I was tinkering with it and now it doesn't write to the text file at all. Here is the code:

```
try (PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(
            new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\A612646\\workspace\\CarParkProject\\PrePaid.txt", true)))) {
        if (AmountofHours < 0 || AmountofHours > 24) {
            out.print(RegNo);
            out.print("\t" + AmountofHours);
            out.print("\t" + CreditCardNo);
            out.print("\t" + expiry);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: I've never used `PrintWriter` but if using it is anything like using `BufferedWriter` or `FileWriter` you need to `.close()` it at the end.

Comment: Have you tried the 'flush()' method?

Comment: as @Arc676 suggested, add `finally{out.close();}`

Comment: is `AmountofHours` actually less than 0 or greater than 24?

Comment: @khelwood There isn't a `PrintWriter(String,boolean)` constructor.  The only constructors that take a `String` as the first arg:  `PrintWriter(String filename, String charset)` and `PrintWriter(String filename)`.

Comment: Why are you putting the `PrintWriter` within parenthesis before going into the actual `try` block?

Comment: @JoshA That's "`try-with-resources`".  The stream will be autoclosed after the `try`.

Comment: @MadConan Ok thanks I hadn't known that, my apologies. With regards to the `(String,boolean)` aspect of your comment, I believe that is for the `FileWriter`, where the `true` appends instead of overwriting.

Comment: @Arc676 @FranMontero - "try-with-resources" guarantees any `AutoCloseable` resource declared within the parentheses. will be closed after the `try`.  The finally block isn't necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure the line:

```
if (AmountofHours < 0 || AmountofHours > 24)
```

should not be

```
if (AmountofHours > 0 && AmountofHours < 24)
```

You're saying if a car is parked less than 0 hours or more than 24 then write a line. I think you intend to say if a car is parked for longer than 0 hours and less than 24...

Comment: I upvoted because the logic is correct, but this doesn't actually answer the question

Comment: I agree with @willow512

Comment: "this doesn't actually answer the question" True.. I didn't really spot a question in there other than the unspoken "Why isn't this working?" and responded to that. I will keep your advice in mind though to always aim for the question...

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with the code!. This code writes the data to the text file. Make sure your logic is correct as willow512 suggested. I would suggest you debug the code to narrow the cause.

```
public class TestFile {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int AmountofHours = 25;
    int RegNo = 52431;
    String CreditCardNo = "5315-XXXX-1456-XXXX";
    String expiry = "15/25";
    try (PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(
         new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\thanigaiarasur\\workspace\\ExploreThings\\PrePaid.txt", true)))) {
        if (AmountofHours < 0 || AmountofHours > 24) {
            out.print(RegNo);
            out.print("\t" + AmountofHours);
            out.print("\t" + CreditCardNo);
            out.print("\t" + expiry);

            System.out.println("printed successfully");
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score -2):

looks like you are opening a Filewriter, but not the File itself.

try this:

```
File file = new File("C:\\Users\\A612646\\workspace\\CarParkProject\\PrePaid.txt");
    if (!file.exists()) 
        file.createNewFile(); //this creates the file :)

FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file);
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);

bw.write("content to write"); //here you will write you stuff
bw.close();
```

Comment: There is no `BufferedWriter.write(String)` method.

Comment: Also, it isn't necessary to create a separate `File` instance.  `FileWriter` and `PrintWriter` will both create the file if it doesn't exist assuming the process has the appropriate access.